# How to use wifi as 3G/2G on Android?

Tags: android

There are some code on Android:

```
if(netType == NetType.3G ||netType == NetType.2G)
{
    //do something
}
```

So I need use 3G/2G to test this code. But for security reason . I can only reach this `if` statement when I using the specific WIFI.

So is there any way to use WIFI and let code looks it as 3G/2G?

Comment: Why would you want to do that

Comment: can you post your whole code ?

Comment: @TimCastelijns The app need be test, and some function work on 2G/3G network condition . But the Intranet for test prevent any net access not in the white list .

Comment: You can use the emulator and simulate various network connections.

Comment: @codemonkey It remind me ! I already forgot it! It's what I want! please write it on answer and I will mark it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [android emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html). With the emulator you can simulate various network connections.